# Select from two tables, single loop

Tags: php, loops, join

how to make this code into in single loop? one single select from two tables!

```
<?

$items = Array();
$kate=mysql_query("select category_id from movies_cat where movie_id='$ids'");

while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($kate))
{
  $kate2=mysql_query("select name_cat from categories where id='$cat[category_id]'");

  while($cat2=mysql_fetch_array($kate2))
  {
    $items[] = $cat2['name_cat'];
  }
}

echo implode(",", $items);

?>
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query Should be `SELECT category_id, name_cat from movies_cat m join categories c where m.category_id = c.id and movie_id='$ids'";` Try this one.